# Azure CLI query parameters not filtering properly

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to query the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` to filer a set of specific groups by checking the `groupType` as below:

```
az rest --method GET --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups" --url-parameters \$groupTypes=Security
```

But I get all the results instead of getting the subset I need.

And what is surprising is, `groupTypes` are all empty `[]` in the result but in the `azure` portal, it has a value (`Security` and some other values)

Why do I see this inconsistency and why it is not filtering? Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The filter seems wrong to me.
The documentation has an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters

```
$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Security')
```

Comment: Hi Juunas, thank you. now it complains about that `Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property groupTypes`. Do you know where I can find the acceptable values for this?

Comment: That's quite odd.. I didn't test this particular query but it is pretty much the same as the one in docs..